# IndexError: list index out of range when sorting list in Z-A order

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
lst=['rocky','parkour','boy','is','a','zoo']
lst_sorted=[]
while len(lst)>0:
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if(lst[i]==max(lst):
            lst_sorted.append(max(lst))
            lst.remove(max(lst))
print(lst_sorted)
print(lst)
```

Output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 6, in 
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: You change the length of your list during for loop, so it can be possible that `i` is, for example, 3, but you have only two elements left in the list

Comment: I really want to know why it is happening?

Comment: Its returning z and rocky, then throwing error. Why?

Comment: Okay, impinge your list has 2 elements, you have a for loop from 0 to 1 (inclusive). `i` is 0, you remove first max element from the list, so the list has the length 1 now. Next `i` is 1, but the list has only one element, so that index `1` points never, this is why you get an error

Comment: You should break from the for loop as soon  as you remove max

Comment: In fact you even don't need for loop, just find a max, append it to sorted list and then remove from the original one. Repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You're removing items from the list after you determine the 'range' of len(lst). So your shrinking the list as you go through it.

If it's easier, in python you can just do list(reversed(sorted(lst)))

```
lst = 'rocky', 'parkour', 'boy', 'is', 'a', 'zoo']
print(list(reversed(sorted(lst))))
# Output: ['zoo', 'rocky', 'parkour', 'is', 'boy', 'a']
```

--

In the comments IOT RnD wanted to understand his implementation better, so here's a quick explanation of how I'd figure it out if it were my code. Here's the original code, slightly modified to print debug important bits.

```
lst=['rocky','parkour','boy','is','a','zoo']
lst_sorted=[]
while len(lst)>0:
    to_iterate = list(range(len(lst)))
    print(f"Iterating over range {to_iterate}")
    for i in to_iterate:
        print(f"On {i}: {lst[i]}, comparing against {max(lst)}. lst={lst}")
        if lst[i]==max(lst):
            print(f"lst[i] == max(lst).  Adding to sorted list and removing from lst.")
            lst_sorted.append(max(lst))
            lst.remove(max(lst))
print(lst_sorted)
print(lst)
```

The output would look like this:

```
Iterating over range [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
On 0: rocky, comparing against zoo. lst=['rocky', 'parkour', 'boy', 'is', 'a', 'zoo']
On 1: parkour, comparing against zoo. lst=['rocky', 'parkour', 'boy', 'is', 'a', 'zoo']
On 2: boy, comparing against zoo. lst=['rocky', 'parkour', 'boy', 'is', 'a', 'zoo']
On 3: is, comparing against zoo. lst=['rocky', 'parkour', 'boy', 'is', 'a', 'zoo']
On 4: a, comparing against zoo. lst=['rocky', 'parkour', 'boy', 'is', 'a', 'zoo']
On 5: zoo, comparing against zoo. lst=['rocky', 'parkour', 'boy', 'is', 'a', 'zoo']
lst[i] == max(lst).  Adding to sorted list and removing from lst.
Iterating over range [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
On 0: rocky, comparing against rocky. lst=['rocky', 'parkour', 'boy', 'is', 'a']
lst[i] == max(lst).  Adding to sorted list and removing from lst.
On 1: boy, comparing against parkour. lst=['parkour', 'boy', 'is', 'a']
On 2: is, comparing against parkour. lst=['parkour', 'boy', 'is', 'a']
On 3: a, comparing against parkour. lst=['parkour', 'boy', 'is', 'a']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eddie\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(f"On {i}: {lst[i]}, comparing against {max(lst)}. lst={lst}")
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Looking at the output you can quickly see that you're shrinking the list 'lst' but you still have indices that point past the end of the array, so you get an error.  you can fix this by 'break'ing after you remove, or reversing your iteration of range(len(lst)) so the indices are always valid, even in the face of a removal.

Comment: this technique I know but I really want to troubleshoot that code. Logically it should work. Actually it is returning z and rocky...then it throwing error

Comment: I'd recommend if you want to understand it, walk through it.  Either with paper and pen, or fire up a debugger like VS code and you can visualize it with a watch window.  That said, I'll see if I can 'debug' it in my answer to help illustrate things.  Stay tuned for an update. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
lst=['rocky','parkour','boy','is','a','zoo']
lst_sorted=[]
while len(lst)>0:
            lst_sorted.append(max(lst))
            lst.remove(max(lst))
print("Revese sorted",lst_sorted)
```